# Adding a header/another row to a pandas dataframe based on some columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a subheader to a pandas data frame based on some attributes. an example is the following:

Current input (already a dataframe with data generated):
[image]

Ideal output:
[image]
Currently, I have all of the attributes in the second row but would like to add a header/above row based on a grouping of certain attributes.

Note: The main key is the order ID not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already have a dataframe with the column names in the inner level shown in your picture. Then one way to do without knowing the column names is:

```
cols = df.columns
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [[''] * len(cols), cols]).map(lambda x: (x[1].split()[0] + ' details', x[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much and yes I have a df. but instead of having it with the details, is there a way to manually add in the column names? I have just showed an example in the question, but I actually have around 40 columns and not all of the grouping ends in "details".

Comment: Yes if you give the right input and right output, better answer can be provided.

Comment: I have updated. Please let me know if I could provide more clarity

Comment: Do you have a mapping(sort of a dict) like `{'SKU Details': ['Product Name', 'SKU Code', 'SKU Expiration Date']}` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("Buyer details", "Buyer Name"),
                                  ("Buyer details", "Buyer Address"),
                                  ("Oder Details", "Order Id"),
                                  ("Oder Details", "Order description"),
                                  ("Oder Details", "Order person"),
                                  ("Item Details", "Item Link"),
                                  ("Item Details", "Item cost")])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have an existing data frame with columns of the second header, and want to group based on the first. is there a way to do that?